# Does a Future get a new thread?

Tags: scala, twitter-util

Does a future implemented like below get a new thread? Apparently it is not(see the output below). Why? What should I do if I want my code to run on a new thread?

```
package MyTest

import com.twitter.util._

import scala.language.postfixOps

object Test {

  def test1 = Future {
    println("BeforeTest", Thread.currentThread())
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    println("AfterTest", Thread.currentThread())
  }

  def test2 = test1 onSuccess { case _ => println("Future on success") }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    println("main", Thread.currentThread())
    test2
    println("main123", Thread.currentThread())
  }
}
```

**Output:**

(main,Thread[run-main-0,5,run-main-group-0])

(BeforeTest,Thread[run-main-0,5,run-main-group-0])

(AfterTest,Thread[run-main-0,5,run-main-group-0])

Future on success

(main123,Thread[run-main-0,5,run-main-group-0])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using twitter futures, not scala futures.
Twitter futures are not multithreaded by default.
You have to use a [FuturePool](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/FuturePool.scala) (passing it an ExecutorService with your threadpool of choice)

Non-tested example (simple enough to work I hope :) ):

```
val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
val pool = FuturePool(executor)

def test1 = pool { 
  println("BeforeTest", Thread.currentThread())
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  println("AfterTest", Thread.currentThread())
}

def test2 = test1 onSuccess { case _ => println("Future on success") }

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  println("main", Thread.currentThread())
  test2
  println("main123", Thread.currentThread())

  executor.shutdown()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. That worked. The program doesn't exit now(I am running through sbt). Why do you think it is?

Comment: you have to shutdown the executor: executor.shutdown()

Answer (score -1):

One of the interesting points of `Future`s is that you don't have to handle threads yourself. How they are executed depends entirely on the implicit `ExecutionContext` that is passed to the `Future.apply()` method (and other methods like `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, etc.). A very gross implementation could create a new thread for each future being computed, but what mostly happens is that such code is executed by a pool of worker threads on the JVM.

Comment: he's using Twitter futures 
import com.twitter.util._